# Paste value after certain delimiter

Tags: r

I have data in the following format:

In Column A:

```
String1__String2__String3
```

In Column B:

```
Value
```

I would like to paste the Value into the String after the first delimiter like this:

```
String1__Value__String2__String3
```

The crucial part of the code I am using now (where I paste the value) is the following line:

```
df2 <-cbind(df[1],apply(df[,2:ncol(df)],2,function(i)ifelse(is.na(i), NA, paste(df[,1],i,sep="_"))))
```

With this code it append the value after the string, like this:

String1__String2__String3__Value

Is there an easy way to rearrange this so the Values will be pasted at the correct place. Or do I have to redo the complete code ?

Thanks

Update, Example:

Column A:

```
Jennifer__DoesSomething__inaCity
```

Column B:

```
2
```

Result now:

```
Jennifer__DoesSomething__inaCity__2
```

Desired result:

```
Jennifer__2__DoesSomething__inaCity
```

The strings Jennifer, DoesSomething, inaCity change and are not the same length. Only the delimiter stays the same. I want to paste after the first delimiter.

Thanks !

Comment: Thanks. But could you elaborate on how I should integrate this in my code. Where should I put this and how should I name this ? The values and Strings are different and not identical. Thanks again.

Comment: Please make a reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Please see the update for a better example. Thanks.

Comment: Added an answer, please have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea. Using `sub` we only replace the first seen pattern. So using `mapply` we replace all the numbers in one column with their corresponding strings on the second column.

```
mapply(function(x, y) sub('__', paste0('__', y, '__'), x), df$v1, df$v2)

#     atsfs__dsfgg__sdgsdg          eeee__FFFF__GGGG 
#"atsfs__3__dsfgg__sdgsdg"     "eeee__5__FFFF__GGGG"
```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(v1 = c("atsfs__dsfgg__sdgsdg", "eeee__FFFF__GGGG"
), v2 = c(3, 5)), .Names = c("v1", "v2"), row.names = c(NA, -2L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how I should apply this to the entire df I have. The df2 line in my code at "paste(df[,1],i,sep="_"))" pastes the string into every cell that has data in it. I never used mapply. Can I add mapply to my code ? Or do I have to redo it. Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean (plus I don't know what your code looks like). The best thing to do is to provide a reproducible example (look at mine) along with expected output. The way you describe it `df$new <-  mapply(.........)` should give the results you want